# How to prevent card SDcard file system corruption when power is abruptly removed or system is improper shutdown?

Tags: boot-issues, filesystem

Raspberry Pi runs on Linux and the filesystem is prone to corruption when power is abruptly removed or improperly shutdown. Sometimes, users are just impatient to wait for proper shutdown to be completed. When corruption happens, RPi may even have problem booting up. How can one prevent filesystem on the SDcard?

Comment: What EVIDENCE do you have for the statement "Raspberry Pi ⋯ filesystem is prone to corruption when power is abruptly removed or improperly shutdown" In almost 3 years with 3 Pi this has never happened to me, and none of the experienced users on this site seem to have problems.

Comment: As Milliways points out, the experience of most users is probably that the pi is no different than any other general purpose computer.  Are you supposed to yank the cord on your desktop?  No.  Why?  Because there are risks such as filesystem corruption.  This is true regardless of hardware brand or OS.  How significant is the risk? That depends on what the system is doing, but usually not that great.  Which is why some people get into the habit of just flicking the switch, but anyone with the mental capacity to actually use a computer can shut it down properly most of the time if they want to.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -h -P now` should be the command burnt into your sub-concious (`sudo sync` *may* ameliorate the damage - shutdown does this as part of its work) but you wouldn't walk out of your house without shutting the door (sync) or properly locking it (shutdown) and expecting everything (data and the filesystem) to be intact and where you left it, at least when you get back!  If you're lucky the wind will have got in and blown stuff around and you can put everything back (fsck) but in reality graffiti and damage (data-corruption) and theft (data-loss) are not *that* surprising.